# Ubuntu 18.04 freeze after log in (dark window and mouse frozen)

Tags: nvidia, gdm, syslinux, gnome-session

I am experiencing an error at the start of my Ubuntu session, and I cannot figure out what it is.
I dualed boot my hp pavilion 15 (windows 10) with a version of Ubuntu 18.04. I installed it with the nomodeset option first then I installed my Nvidia gpu (geforce gtx 1050) by downloading the proposer version on Nvidia website. Then I installed a Nvidia driver using ´´apt-get install Nvidia-driver-440´´. Then I have an issue just after logging in to my session, it seems to be with the gnome session but I don’t know how to solve it.

Please can someone help me? I am stuck with this issue for too long.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the gdm problem should fix it for you.  Be patient. GDM 3.34.1 is super unstable as we speak. login/corruption/not seeing enviroments proper etc.. To name a few issues I've been just learning about